# Mobile Drop Menu not working on click for IOS

Tags: html, ios, mobile, drop-down-menu

My drop down menu does not work on IOS application. Can anybody help me to figure out why?

```
my CSS: 
.onclick-menu {position: relative;display: inline-block;width:70%;line-height:auto}
.onclick-menu:before {content:"Menu"}
.onclick-menu:focus {pointer-events: none}
.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {opacity: 1;visibility: visible;pointer-events: auto}
.onclick-menu-content {background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);line-height:auto;font-variant:normal;margin-right:10%;margin-top:1%;width:100%;position: absolute;z-index: 1000;opacity: 0;visibility: hidden;transition: visibility 0.5s}
.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content span {opacity: 1;visibility: visible;pointer-events: auto}

My html link:
<div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu"><ul class="onclick-menu-content"><ul><li>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use somebody else Knowledge and it worked much more better I just need to customize with some adjustment to my application. I hope it help you too guys, see below web link with some different solutions:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2015/06/responsive-navigation-tutorials-demo